# Trying to convert pseudo code into Python code

Tags: python

I have a pseudocode that I need to turn into functional Python code and see what it prints.

I am having problem understanding how to convert certain parts. n has to be an number like 7 for exampel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

```
PrintThis(n)
       for i=1 to n
           str = " " //empty string
           for j=1 to i
               str = str+"x"
           print (str)
```

This is what I got:

```
def PrintThis(n):
    for i in n:
        str = " "
        for j in i:
            str = str + "x"
        print(str)
```

Comment: `for i in n:` should be `for i in range(n):` same for `j`.

Comment: `n` is just a number. you need to convert it to something which `for` loop can consume. `range(n)` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

*for i=1 to n* is equivalent to *for i in range(n)* in Python

```
def PrintShape(n):
    for i in range(n):
        str = " "
        for j in range(i):
            str = str + "x"
        print(str)
    

PrintShape(5)
```